# Objective-C Struct problems

Tags: objective-c

I have a student structure that provides the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Grades.m"
#import <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    NSString *myName;
    struct Grades *myGrades;
};

void setName(struct Student *s, NSString *name);
void ssetGrades(struct Student *s, NSString *gradeList);

void setName(struct Student *s, NSString *name)
{
    s->myName = name;
}

void ssetGrades(struct Student *s, NSString *gradeList)
{
    printf("\n\nWorking\n\n");
    setGrades(s->myGrades, gradeList);
    printf("\n\nWorking");
}
```

I have a grades structure that provides the following:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define null NULL

struct Grades
{
    double sgrades[100];
    int length;
};

void setGrades(struct Grades *grades, NSString *gradeList);
void setGrade(int spot, double grade, struct Grades *grades);

void setGrades(struct Grades *grades, NSString *gradeList)
{
    NSString *a = [gradeList substringToIndex:1];
    NSString *b = [gradeList substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 19)];
    int ln = [a integerValue];

    grades->length = ln;

    double grade;
    int x = 1;
    int prev = 1;
    int y;

    int z = 0;

    for(y=0;y<ln;y++)
    {
        while(x < [b length] && [b characterAtIndex:x] != ' ')
        {
            z++;
            x++;
        }

        NSString *sub = [b substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(prev, z)];
        grade = [sub doubleValue];
        printf("%d %d %d %lf\n", y, prev, z, grade);
        prev += z+1;
        x++;
        z=0;
        setGrade(y, grade, grades);
    }
}

void setGrade(int spot, double grade, struct Grades *grades)
{
    grades->sgrades[spot] = grade;
}
```

And finally, I have a main function with the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Grades.m"
#import "Student.m"
#import <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    struct Grades test; 
    setGrades(&test, @"5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88");
    toString(&test);
    printf("\nsum = %lf", getSum(&test));   
    printf("\nnum grades = %d", getNumGrades(&test));   
    printf("\nlow grade = %lf", getLowGrade(&test));        
    printf("\nhigh grade = %lf", getHighGrade(&test));


    struct Student stu;
    setName(&stu, @"Billy Bob");
    ssetGrades(&stu, @"5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88");

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Now whenever I get to the `ssetGrades (&stu, @"5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88")` line in the main, it freezes up and says that the program has stopped working. Any guesses why and if so, how can I fix this error?

NOTE: This is all done in Notepad++ on Windows 7

Comment: Why are you using `struct`s and functions instead of creating classes?

Comment: Your biggest issue is passing the `struct`s as pointers. `struct` values should be passed by reference, not by pointers.

Comment: Actually it's not so much that you pass struct pointers to the functions, it's that you have a struct pointer to `Grades` in your `Student` struct. Change that to a non-pointer and it should work better.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: It's back and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is your definition of your `Student` structure. Change the `Grades` reference so it isn't a pointer:

```
struct Student
{
    NSString *myName;
    struct Grades myGrades;
};
```

The problem with the pointer is that you never initialize the pointer. By removing the pointer the memory issues causing the crash will go away.

As a result of this change, you need to change a few other things. The call to `setGrades` needs to pass the address of `myGrades`:

```
setGrades(&(s->myGrades), gradeList);
```

Even better would be to replace all of this struct/function code with actual classes.

Comment: Here's the thing. I shortened my code above to try to make it more simple to answer, but the problem is that I have `void setGrades(struct Grades *grades, NSString *gradeList);
void setGrade(int spot, double grade, struct Grades *grades);
double getSum(struct Grades *grades); 
double getLowGrade(struct Grades *grades);
double getHighGrade(struct Grades *grades);
int getNumGrades(struct Grades *grades);
void toString(struct Grades *grades);` in my Grades structure. This leads to several errors since I just set it to a non-pointer and these all take pointers

Comment: What should I do to fix lines, such as `int sgetNumGrades(struct Student *s)
{
    return s->myGrades->length;
}`

Comment: That would be `return s->myGrades.length;`. Use the `->` when you have a pointer to a struct and use `.` when you don't have a pointer to the struct.